# Filter lines in ongoing process, using Ruby

Tags: ruby, process, stdout

I have an EDA vendor SW1, which outputs STDOUT information to a different EDA vendor SW2. The SW2 prints out in a GUI, as the run continues.

I need some way of filtering out certain things, from  STDOUT, in "real time", instead of getting lines:

```
hey now
oops
hello
```

I will get:

```
hey now
hello
```

I tried to use:

```
Popen3.popen2e( 'run_eda', 'script name' ){ |i,o,t|
...
}
```

And using timeout when reading `o`, and timeout when trying to run `t.value()`
I get nothing in pipe `o`, but the run completes well.

I looked at other answers here, but they don't handle STDERR, as far as I know.

Any recomendations?

Comment: It's difficult to tell what you're trying to do based on your code and example output. If you're piping output from one script to another, you might want to look at using the built-in `grep` tool, which is part of *nix. (We can't tell what OS you're on.) Something like `foo | grep -v 'oops' | bar` is very standard. Wanting to do it all in a particular language is nice, but there's a HUGE amount of useful code that's prewritten and available to you in the OS, so it's worth your time to take advantage of it and write code that hasn't been invented already.

Comment: True. The thing is that I want the lines filtered printed to a different file.
Also, there are cases when filtering a line depends on what was printed in the preceding line...

Comment: Then that information needs to be in your question, not a comment, and you need to show how you tried to solve those problems.